# Find the highest partial derivative between two functions

Tags: functions, derivatives

I have two functions with the following characteristics:

$$\text{1)} f(x) \gt g(x), \, \text{for all $x$ in $(0,1]$}$$
$$\text{2)} f(0)=g(0)=0$$
$$\text{3) Both are twice differentiable and concave in $x$}$$

Let's say that $x,y$ are variables in $[0,1]$, such that $x+y=1$.

Is it possible to show that $f'(x) \gt g'(1-x)$ or if the opposite holds, or it is impossible to conclude?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why in the title talk about "partial derivative"?

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ and $g$ are functions of one only variable I wouldn't speak of partial derivative. y is just the symetric of x with respect to $\frac{1}{2}$

Let's take $f(x)=sin(x\pi)$ and $g(x)=0.9 \cdot f(x)$.

They comply with the characteristics you listed :

1. $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x$ in $]0,1]$
2. $f(0)=g(0)=0$
3. Both are twice differentiable and concave in $x$ on $[0,1]$

Now $f'(x)=\pi\cdot cos(x\pi)$ and $g'(x)=0.9 \cdot f'(x)$

Let's show that $f'(1-x)=-f'(x)$ substituting $x$ by $1-x$
$$f'(1-x)=\pi\cdot cos(\pi-x\pi) = -\pi\cdot cos(x\pi)=-f'(x)$$ 
since $$cos(\pi-x)=-cos(x)$$

The same for $g'$ which is just $0.9\cdot f'(x)$

Looking at $f'(x)=\pi\cdot cos(x\pi)$ we see it's positive on $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$ and negative on $[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ (see properties of $cos$ function)

The same for $g'$ which is just $0.9\cdot f'(x)$

Therefore :

1. $f′(x)>-g'(x)$ on $[0, \frac{1}{2}[$ because $f'$ and $g'$ are positive on this interval
2. $f′(x)<-g'(x)$ on $]\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ because $f'$ and $g'$ are negative on this interval

which can be also written :

1. $f′(x)>g'(1-x)$ on $[0, \frac{1}{2}[$ and
2. $f′(x)<g'(1-x)$ on $]\frac{1}{2}, 1]$

Those functions $f$ and $g$ are an example of functions which comply with 1)2)3) but for which none of your assumptions hold (nor < or >)